# Getting HTML input value in JavaFX WebView?

Tags: java, html, input, javafx, webview

Is it possible to get the value of a HTML input inside a WebView in JavaFX?

If so, how would I use an event so the value updates automatically?

Example App:

```
package webviewinputvalue;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class WebviewInputValue extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        WebView test = new WebView();
        WebEngine run = test.getEngine();
        run.loadContent("<textarea></textarea>");
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(test);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Which creates a simple window like this:

[image: Test application]

**Question:** Is it possible to get the value of the textarea using JavaFX? If so, how *should* I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR: Yes, it's possible, but it requires a bit of a hacky workaround.

First of all, I'm going to move the HTML to it's own separate file, to make editing easier, and just create cleaner code in general.

#### editor.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Example Live-view</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea placeholder="Typing 'exit' will kill the program."></textarea>
        
        <script>
            document.querySelector("textarea").addEventListener("keyup", function(){
                
                window.status = this.value;
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The basic structure is really simple, but what about the `<script>` element? What does it do?

```
document.querySelector("textarea").addEventListener("keyup", function(){
     window.status = this.value;
});
```

AFAIK, it isn't possible to straight out get the value of an input in JavaFX, so you have to make a workaround. In this case, I'm setting the window status with the textarea value, whenever there is a `keyup` event in the textarea.

Now we need to set up the webview in our JavaFX.

#### WebviewInputValue.java

```
package webviewinputvalue;

public class WebviewInputValue extends Application {
    
    private WebView InitWebview(){
        
        //Create browser
        WebView browser = new WebView();
        WebEngine render = browser.getEngine();
        
        //Load simple HTML
        String editor = WebviewInputValue.class.getResource("editor.html").toExternalForm();
        render.load(editor);
        
        //Listen for state change
        render.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((ov, o, n) -> {
            if (Worker.State.SUCCEEDED == n) {
                render.setOnStatusChanged(webEvent -> {
                        
                    //Call value change
                    onValueChange(webEvent.getData());
                });
            }
        });
        
        return browser;
    }
    
    //called when value changes
    private void onValueChange(String data){
        
        //Print out data
        System.out.println(data);
        
        //If the data is equal to "exit", close the program
        if("exit".equals(data)){
            
            //Print goodbye message
            System.out.println("Received exit command! Goodbye :D");
            
            //Exit
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        
        //Create browser
        WebView browser = InitWebview();
                
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(browser);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Again, very simple code. Let's dig into it:

```
private WebView InitWebview(){
    
    //Create browser
    WebView browser = new WebView();
    WebEngine render = browser.getEngine();
    
    //Load simple HTML
    String editor = WebviewInputValue.class.getResource("editor.html").toExternalForm();
    render.load(editor);
    
    //Listen for state change
    render.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((ov, o, n) -> {
        if (Worker.State.SUCCEEDED == n) {
            render.setOnStatusChanged(webEvent -> {
                    
                //Call value change
                onValueChange(webEvent.getData());
            });
        }
    });
    
    return browser;
}
```

First we create the webview and engine, then load the `editor.html` file into the webview. Next, we fetch the loadWorker, which is what controls the `window.status` object we are writing to with the JS. We then get the `state` property, and add an listener. If the listener is added successfully, then listen for a change event.

When the change event, we'll call our `onValueChange` method:

```
//called when value changes
private void onValueChange(String data){
    
    //Print out data
    System.out.println(data);
    
    //If the data is equal to "exit", close the program
    if("exit".equals(data)){
        
        //Print goodbye message
        System.out.println("Received exit command! Goodbye :D");
        
        //Exit
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

This is extremely simple. `onValueChange` is called with the `textarea` value as the `data` parameter. In this case, I'm printing it to the console. If I type `exit` into the textarea, then it will print a goodbye message and close the application.

[image: finished project]

And that's it! If you run the above code, then it'll log the textarea value into the console real-time!

#### Note:

Your project structure should look this, with editor in the same dir as the java file, if you want this code to work straight off:

[image: structure]

Also, I'm obviously missing the imports in the java code.

Answer (score 1):

3 years later, but I hope it will help someone. I found how to get text from `TextArea` without changing html page

```
Runnable check = () -> {            
    WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();
    if (engine != null) {
        Document document = engine.getDocument();
        if (document != null) {
            Element element = document.getElementById("samlResponse");
            if (element instanceof HTMLTextAreaElement) {
                HTMLTextAreaElement textArea = (HTMLTextAreaElement) element;
                String text = textArea.getValue();
                if (text != null && !text.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("BINGO:\n" + text);
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

new Thread(() -> {
    while (true) {
        Platform.runLater(check);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1_000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}).start();
```