# allow subscript and superscript text in textarea

Tags: javafx

I want to allow superscript and subscript text in textarea. After searching a bit, I stumbled upon javafx.scene.text.FontPosition https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/javafx/javafx/1.1/docs/api/javafx.scene.text/javafx.scene.text.FontPosition.html that is used to describe font as superscript, subscript or regular. But I'm not able to figure out how to change the current font flow from regular to subscript/superscript and vice-versa while typing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "WebView" node for richtext fields. Sample codes are below. Hopes it is useful.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class WebviewSample extends Application {
   @Override
   public void start(final Stage stage) {
   stage.setWidth(400);
   stage.setHeight(500);
   Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());


   final WebView browser = new WebView();
   final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();

   ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
   scrollPane.setContent(browser);

   String htmlText = "<b> This is bold text </b>"
                    + "<br/>" 
                    + "<h1> This is h1 text </h1>"
                    + "<br/>"
                    + "<h2 style=\"background-color:red\">Background-color set by using red</h2>";

webEngine.loadContent(htmlText);

scene.setRoot(scrollPane);

stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);
    }
}
```

Output is like:

[image]

Comment: thanks @GltknBtn for the reply. I just have a small doubt regarding the sample code. How can I put the text in subscript while the user is typing. For example, while using a document editor like MS-Word, we can put text in subscript or superscript while typing. Can WebView provides such functionality?

Comment: You can provide html text from another field such as text area or text field and show the subscript and superscript in Web view. Sample html text with subscript and super like this: " 
<h1>A=B<sub>c</sub>D<sup>2</sup>"

Comment: Sorry for invalid script it would be like this:
<h1>A=B<sub>c</sub>D<sup>2</sup></h1>

Comment: thanks @GltknBtn again. I have seen this [ink](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25415049/getting-html-input-value-in-javafx-webview). So I will try to mix ur solution and the solution in the link as well. Hope it turns out right.

Comment: You are welcome.  If the link you have seen is not useful, you can look at javafx Html editor. Maybe it can be useful.   Sample link: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/editor.htm

Comment: Yup @GltknBtn. tried looking that. but the problem is there is no option for subscript and superscript. although there are several open source html editors available like ekit, but they provide spell checker feature which i don't want. although with help of unicode and the solution in the link, i'm able to get the text to subscript. but now i'm facing with the issue of how to set the textarea text with the subscript text. any ideas?